# How to see on which Access Point I am connected that is setup on RADIUS server?

Tags: wireless-networking, ssid, radius

There are some access point with the same name of SSID in my office. All of them are setup on RADIUS server, with Authentication Method: WPA2-Enterprise.

How can I see which Access Point I'm connected to?

Comment: What OS are you using?  The procedure is different for Mac OSX, Windows, or Linux.

Comment: Here there are more general answers:
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/17582/finding-out-which-wifi-ap-the-device-used-to-access-the-network

Answer (score 5):

On Mac OSX you can get a lot of details by holding down the Option key and then clicking on the WiFi menu icon. ([Ref](http://osxdaily.com/2011/06/15/get-detailed-wifi-info-from-the-menu-bar/))

Comment: Windows 7 Professional, Enterprise and Home

Comment: FYI (in case it's not obvious), this is labeled as the "BSSID" on this menu! (a BSSID is the MAC specific to a certain AP on a network)